# Jquery tabs overwriting content links

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Im using Jquery tabs, and for some reason it is over-righting links with an id of #ui-tabs[object , object] ( a href="#ui-tabs[object , object]" ) 
an ideas why this is happening?

below is a sample of my structure

JS

```
$(function () {
      $(".Whatson-today").tabs();
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="Whatson-today">

<ul id="WOT-TabNav">

    <li class="WOToday">    
        <a href='#tabs-1'>
            What's on Today
        </a>

    </li>

    <li class="WOTomorrow">    
        <a href='#tabs-2'>
            What's on Tomorrow
        </a>

    </li>

</ul>


<div id='tabs-1'>   
    <ol>

        <li>
            <ol>
                <li class="WOT-Time">
                    7:30 PM
                </li>
                <li class="WOT-Title">
                 <h2 style="display:none;"><a  href="#">test</a></h2>
                    <h2><a href="http://somelink.com">somelink</a></h2>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>

    </ol>
</div>   

<div id='tabs-2'>   

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see the problem: http://jsbin.com/utepat/1/edit

Comment: strange, after taking out all scripts on the page i found that the ui-tabs.js i was using was not up-to-date which was causing the error. basically .tabs() was acting as if the top level was the navigation.